# How to create a decorator that accepts an abstract class in Typescript

Tags: typescript, generics, abstract-class, decorator

I have a class decorator that adds a few properties to the class passed in.

```ts
type Class<T, TArgs extends any[] = any[]> = (...args: TArgs) => T;

export function myDecorator<T extends Class<any>>(Target: T) {
  const MyDecoratedClass = class extends Target {
    prop: string;
    fn(arg: string) {
      console.log(this.prop);
    }
  };

  const name = `Decorated${Target.name}`;
  Object.defineProperty(MyDecoratedClass, 'name', { value: name });

  return MyDecoratedClass as typeof MyDecoratedClass & T;
}

class MyClass extends myDecorator(SomeClass)<string> {
  foo: string;
  // ...
}

class MyImplementedClass extends myDecorator(SomeAbstractClass)<string> {
  foo: string;
  // ...
}
```

It works fine for non-abstract classes, but attempting to use it on abstract classes results in the error:

> ```
> Cannot assign an abstract constructor type to a non-abstract constructor type. ts(2345)
> ```

This error message leads me to believe there *must* be a way to specify a type that accepts an abstract constructor type, otherwise it would (or should have) read something equivalent to `Types cannot bind to abstract constructors.`

I have a `Class` type:

```ts
type Class<T, TArgs extends any[] = any[]> = new(...args: TArgs) => T;
```

I thought *maybe* I could use the `abstract` keyword to achieve my goal:

```ts
type AbstractClass<T, TArgs extends any[] = any[]> = abstract new(...args: TArgs) => T;

// or

interface AbstractClass<T, TArgs extends any[] = any[]> {
  abstract new(...args: TArgs): T;
}
```

but no dice.  The first results in a syntax error.  The second results in

> ```
> 'abstract' modifier cannot appear on a type member. ts(1070)
> ```

---

#### Update

I found a case-specific workaround.  This decorator is used specifically for React components.  Therefore, I can create a base class, and extend that in my abstract class:

```ts
class DecoratedClass<P = {}, S = {}, SS = {}> extends myDecorator(Component)<P, S, SS> { }

abstract class MyClass extends DecoratedClass {
  // ...
}
```

Comment: Could you please share `myDecorator`?

Comment: Sure, though I don't see what difference it will make.

Comment: it will make zero difference. I'm just curious :D. Interesting pattern

Comment: @captain-yossarian Lol, fair.  I wrote a super simple class decorator.  The actual one is my company's IP, but it essentially handles mobx's `autorun()` and `observe()` so that the disposers are run when `componentWillUnmount()` is called.